# in java programming use a scanner class along with switch case statement using numbers

Tags: java

Can anybody tell me how to use "switch-case" for numbers along with scanner class, so that a number read from the keyboard should compare with switch cases given and final output should be printed?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Switchcase{
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int age;
    Scanner bhavya = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter your age:");
    age = bhavya.nextInt();
    switch (age) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("you can crawl");
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("you can talk");
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("you can get in trouble");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("i dnt know how old you are");
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is, hands down, the most poorly formatted post I have ever seen.  You need to fix up that code before anyone will even spend the time to read your entire post.

Comment: Edited code to be formatted doesn't; stackoverflow errored ("Edit has to be a suggested edit?? Not sure what that means).

Comment: Work on your Code Readability. From a quick look , You should println to ask the user to enter the number before trying to scan it from the input buffer..

Comment: @Zimm3r The best place to look for answers to questions like that is meta. If the question hasn't been answered before, you can ask it there. Fortunately for you, this question has already been answered, because I asked it a while back. :) http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190687/this-edit-would-have-to-be-a-suggested-edit-edit-button-grayed-out

Answer (score 2):

Your program works ... apart from the fact that you are not dealing with the case where the user enters something that is not a valid integer.

You need to either use [`Scanner.hasNextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29) to test if the next token is an integer or catch and diagnose the exception that is thrown by [`Scanner.nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) when it can't read an `int`.